# Grid is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am learning how to create a `Class Library (Windows Store apps)` and used a `UserControl` template to add a user control to it.

Then I added a `Grid` tag to accompanying XAML. However, the tag is underlined with blue squiggles and when I hover over the tag there is

> Grid is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

tooltip shows up.

The library seems to build without errors. I've added the library to an application and use the control in its code. The application is also builds just fine. However, when I run the application I get `XamlParseException` exception.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 RTM. Both the library and the application reference only two standard assemblies (`.NET for Windows Store apps` and `Windows`).

What I might done wrong and how should I fix the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reposting comment as answer]

I was able to complete the steps with no issues, and it appears you were able to as well. Perhaps there was some other inadvertent modification/setting that was made?

Answer (score 39):

In my case I switched from Debug to Release, and then back, and the error was gone.

Comment: walking into the office at monday morning "here we go already encountering these weird problems". saved my day

Comment: The issue started right after a VS 2019 update. Did everything including VS restarts and computer reboots. This was the fix.

Comment: Why did this work, not sure - but it did

Comment: Wow! Do this before trying anything else.

Answer (score 29):

Go to **"Build > Configuration Manager..."** and Make a new platform for **x86** for all your projects.
It doesn't have to be the active one, you can leave that as **Any CPU**.

Hope it works as for mine...

Answer (score 6):

I've recently had the same error and found the following in the output window:

`10>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(268,9): error MC6000: Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list.`

The solution for me was to add the missing references to my project.

Comment: Similar for me, when I looked at my references, there were a lot of warning icons. It turned out that I just needed to build my project to restore nuget packages, then close and re-open the solution.

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to set the "Target framework" in application-properties to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bit of a "catch-all" for a number of XAML resource errors. I've found two causes so far:

1. Declaring a Resource outside of the appropriate context- e.g. directly in a UserControl tags, not UserControl.Resources.
2. Forgetting to include the correct namespace for the "unsupported" class. Example in a basic ResourceDictionary, with no sys namespace defined:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary> 
       <sys:string>I'm not supported</sys:string>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my similar issue of..

`UserControl is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project`

.. by removing the PresentationFramework reference and re-adding it via nuget.

Answer (score 0):

This is xaml getting itself confused. I have the error on one project and not on another. Have a look at the top of the xaml before the grid error and see if there are any references to other controls. Try making a modification that will cause and error and rebuilding one of those controls. Then put it back the way it was to get a succesful build and see if this makes the grid error go away. (it did for me)

Answer (score 0):

Much Like [Felix D.s answer](/questions/13095131/grid-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-presentation-foundation-wpf-project#answer-28745328), I found from the .csproj file a reference was removed.
Obviously replace the 3 with your needed framework, or use the project properties to set the version ( i think that adds this reference )

[Evil Dog Pie](/questions/13095131/grid-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-presentation-foundation-wpf-project#answer-28745328) was step 1 for me, as some other issues came up. There is always a heap of information in the output log

```
<Reference Include="PresentationFramework">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the low version of .NET that you have chosen in your project.

To solve the problem, select the Project from the up menu and then select your Project Properties and from the part of Target Framework select higher version of .NET Framework!

I hope your problem is solved.
Yours sincerely

Answer (score 0):

I had a different reason for this issue **after merging git branches inside of Visual Studio**.

**In all `*.csproj` files a project reference** to one of my projects **was deleted**. (A project with all my base classes.) As result I had 2500 build errors. Many of them like *Grid / UserControl / etc. is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project*

Solution:

1. Check the git diff for changed `*.csproj` files. If there are only deleted project references, you can use the *revert changes* feature. If there are also wanted changes, undo the deletions manually.
2. Call clean solution and close Visual Studio!
3. Restart Visual Studio and build everything again.

This solved all the strange problems in my case. (Visual Studio 2022)

Note: It's important to close Visual Studio after cleaning. Without restart there were still many strange build errors. (about 500 instead of 2500)